# Losing form input data when reinvoking a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-view

I have a simple multi-view Angular application that implements a wizard, so each time a user clicks "Next" button, the app navigates to the next view, and same for "Back" button. I have a `$routeProvider` config that binds all views to the same controller. Each view represents a chunk of a huge form with input fields, and `$routeProvider` manages navigation across them:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/salespoints', {
        templateUrl: 'salespoints',
        controller: 'main'
    })
    .when('/users', {
        templateUrl: 'users',
        controller: 'main'
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'partner',
        controller: 'main'
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

The problem is that each time a user clicks "Next" or "Back", the controller is invoked, so all the `$scope` changes that were made on previous steps are simply lost:

```
app.controller('main', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log('controller invoked'); // appears each time a user presses "Next" or "Back", hence re-instantiation of $scope
}]);
```

The application is small enough to turn to `$rootScope` in case every other method fails, but I just would like to avoid that as an anti-pattern.

What's the best way to keep `$scope` in latest state, with all changes made from the very beginning of app instance's lifecycle, and without re-instantiating it on every change of view?

Comment: You should use a service if you wan't a container level

Answer (score 5):

Use a service to keep your form data and inject it into your controller.

```
angular.module('app').factory('formService', function () {
   var data = {};
   return {
      data: data
   };
});

angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', function(formService) {
   this.formData = formService.data;
});
```

Comment: In this particular case, how should I catch the view switch event, if not explicitly listening to it? And if it's the only way, `ng-route` is of no use, and the navigation logic becomes too complicated.

Comment: You leave your routes as is, you just change the controller to pull the `formData` values from the service instead.

Answer (score 1):

Angular **controllers** are **instanciated each time you have a new** `ng-controller` in your template.

Angular **services** are **instanciated only once**, at the first time you need it, because they are **singleton**.

So angular services should be use to store data, especially data shared between multiple controllers instances (even if it's the same controller definition as in your example).

Answer (score 1):

So, according to [the advice of @joao-leal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31161732/1287643), I moved the data persistence to a new service and subscribed to `$scope` updates via `$scope.$watch`. The overall solution resulted into a quite simple code chunk:

```
app.factory('formPersistence', function () {
    var data = {};

    var get = function () {
        return data;
    };

    var set = function (updated) {
        data = updated;
    }

    var reset = function () {
        data = {};
    }

    return {
        get: get,
        set: set,
        reset: reset
    };
});

app.controller('main', ['$scope', 'formPersistence', function ($scope, formPersistence) {
    $scope.data = formPersistence.get();

    $scope.$watch('data', function () {                
        formPersistence.set($scope.data);
    });
}]);
```